# Python - Creating a label/

Tags: python, ms-word, label, pdf-generation

[image: Label for Product]

I have been asked to automate a label creation for a product. (see image)

It will basically work by taking in the raw input product code, slicing that string and linking it to the codes meaning which I can do.

I am at a bit of a loss on how to populate the values in this form/label.

Has anyone got any ideas on where to start?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.  StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Comment: You will also need to describe where you're stuck in this process.  It seems that you already know how to fetch the data, given the product code.  You haven't given us any idea of how that works, nor how raw data values might get into whatever form you're using for the label.  Without input/output specs and perhaps some starting code, we don't have a clear problem description for giving you help.